# How to change XML namespace with lxml in Python?

Tags: python, lxml, xml-namespaces

I have an XML file like below, and I've parsed it with lxml into Tree.
What I want to do is change xml declaration from `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"` to `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/"`.

```
<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
  <tr>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td>Bananas</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

But I failed to get the `xmlns` attribute or change it by set the `tag` property. Any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can locate the `table` element and re-set the attribute value accessing the `xmlns` attribute via the `.attrib` dictionary:

```
In [1]: from lxml import html

In [2]: data = """<html><body><table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
    ...:   <tr>
    ...:       <td>Apples</td>
    ...:       <td>Bananas</td>
    ...:   </tr>
    ...: </table></body></html>"""

In [3]: root = html.fromstring(data)

In [4]: root.find('.//table').attrib['xmlns'] = "http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/"

In [5]: print(html.tostring(root, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
<html><body><table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/">
  <tr>
      <td>Apples</td>
      <td>Bananas</td>
  </tr>
</table></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually recommend using `BeautifulSoup` for this kind of changes into the html structure:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
t = """
<table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
 <tr>
     <td>Apples</td>
     <td>Bananas</td>
 </tr>
</table>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(t, 'lxml')
soup.table['xmlns'] = 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/'
print(soup)
```

and it should return:

```
<html><body><table xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/">
<tr>
<td>Apples</td>
<td>Bananas</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

and we are still using `lxml` but inside BeautifulSoup